# Google Closure calling undefined functions in advanced mode

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Using Google Closure Compiler I have discovered that under certain circumstances it will call an undefined local functions. The minimal example that shows this that I have found is this:

```
var apa = {
    /** @this {!Object} */
    foo: function () { this.bar(id()); },
    bar: function (x) { return [x]; }
};

apa.foo();
```

Which compiles to

```
(function(){this.a(id())})();
```

When compiling with `closure --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`. The default compilation (without any options) compiles to this:

```
var apa={foo:function(){this.bar(id())},bar:function(a){return[a]}};apa.foo();
```

In the minimal version `this.a` is undefined.

During my research I have not found any sign of any reason for this behaviour and I'm honestly pretty confused about it. Is this a bug in closure or me making some kind of faulty assumption?

(Any suggestion on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated since I'm in great need of minimizing the js as much as humanly possible without doing it by hand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things with your example causing problems:

1. The `id` function isn't defined in the code sample. The compiler will assume it is an external function. When a `VERBOSE` warning level is set, warnings or errors will be emitted for this case.
2. You are using the `this` keyword outside of a constructor or prototype method. Since the compiler can flatten your properties all the way to global variables, which object the `this` keyword references may change.
3. The `@this` annotation tells the compiler that the the `this` keyword in the function will be a non-null object. I'm sure you used this to silence the warning the compiler issued about the previous point. However it is now your responsibility to explicitly set the `this` object when invoking the function using either `call` or `apply`. In addition, the property `bar` is not defined on the type `Object` and so the compiler will be even more confused.

Below is a corrected version of your example:

```
function id() {
  // this definition was created as an illustration and to prevent the 
  // example from being removed as dead code.
  var id_ = math.random();
  window.console.log(id);
  return id_;
}

var apa = {
  foo: function () {
    apa.bar(id());
    // id could also be called externally as follows:
    // apa.bar(window['id']());
  },
  bar: function (x) { return [x]; }
};

apa.foo();
```

To further understand these issues, I recommend reading:

- [Which compilation is right for me?](http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/09/which-compilation-level-is-right-for-me.html)
- [Understanding the Restrictions Imposed by Closure-Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations)

Comment: 1. Why would there be a problem with `id` being assumed to be external? It's irrelevant to my problem and really only serves to show the problem since the entire code could be optimized away if there aren't any external calls.
2,3. This seems to be my actual problem, I was not aware that `this` was being interpreted in that way so thank you for explaining, it really made things clearer. I confess to not having expert-level knowledge on how closure compiles JS, I'm only doing assumptions based on my knowledge about compilers and code optimization in general.

Comment: Also: In the "corrected version" you are replacing one undefined function (`id`) with two (`math.random` and `window.console.log`)... the result is basically the same... the corrected version should rather have been:

    var apa = {
      foo: function () { apa.bar(id()); },
      bar: function (x) { return [x]; }
    };

    apa.foo();

Keeping the functionality of my example but with expected behaviour.

Comment: I made up a definition for the `id` function. There is nothing special about my definition other than it has side effects (`console.log`) and it only uses external functions included in the Closure-compiler default externs file. If `id` is truly external, then you should either define it in a custom extern file or explicitly called as an external (`window['id']()`).

Comment: but that doesn't really affect the outcome of the optimization, id is not defined, therefore it will be interpreted as a side effect and not be optimized away. Either way it's, as far as I can understand it, unrelated to my problem. Thanks for giving me an answer to my question, it was very helpful.